# Rails routes.rb get "user/new" vs get "user#new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails' routes.rb, what's difference between `get "user/new"` vs `get "user#new"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know:

```
get "user/new"
```

means when you'll type in the url: `localhost/user/new` it will be processed by `users controller` action `new`

```
"user#new"
```

is used when you want some specific url to be processed by a specific `controller` and `action`, for exemple when you open `localhost/profiles` you want it to be processed by `users_controller` action `show`.

```
get "profile", to: "users#show"
```

or, `localhost/edit_profile`:

```
get "edit_profile", to: "users#edit
```